# Python's unpack function in C#

Tags: c#, python, arrays, string, unpack

I am looking for a way of getting the result of this procedure in C#. To be precise, I am trying to unpack data from a binary string, according to the given format (the method should return an array). Please refer to http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html for more information.

```
struct.unpack('!hh', data[2:6])
```

Is there a way of doing such in C#?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think [BinaryReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.aspx) is what you want.

Something like this would be the equivalent (assuming `data` is a byte array):

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(data)) {
    using (var reader = new BinaryReader(stream)) {
        stream.Seek(2, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        var value1 = reader.ReadInt16();
        var value2 = reader.ReadInt16();
    }
}
```

This should skip the first 2 bytes, then load the next 4 bytes into two `short` variables.

Comment: One thing that can bite you with BinaryReader: it has fixed endianness. The unpack functions let you specify different endianness, but .NET doesn't make it easy. If you need to control that, you have to resort to using streams, possibly Array.Reverse(), and BitConverter.